# "maps is offline check your network connection" on Mobile Data

Tags: google-maps

Google maps is not able to connect when not on wifi, how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem. 
It happened after I put a secondary SIM card for a while and used it. 
Then when I switched back to the original Sim card while keeping the second one in, I didn't have a connection anymore.
Seems it gets stuck trying to use the secondary sim card even if it's off.
Solution: Remove the secondary card.